# WTL Adding a tooltip to a dynamically created button

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi, wtl

I've been working on a modal dialog using the Windows Template Library where I need to dynamically create buttons and add tool-tips to them. I can't seem to find the correct way to do this:

```cpp
// CMyDialog.h
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"

class CMyDialog : public CDialogImpl<CIdleDialog> {

public:

    enum { IDD = IDD_IDLEDIALOG };

protected:

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMyDialog)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_INITDIALOG, OnInitDialog)
    END_MSG_MAP()

    LRESULT OnInitDialog(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam,
                         BOOL &bHandled)
    {
        CRect dialog_rect(0, 0, 600, 400);
        MoveWindow(&dialog_rect);
        CenterWindow();

        CButton btn;
        CRect btn_rect(10, 10, 200, 30);
        btn.Create(this->m_hWnd, btn_rect, L"Test Button",
                   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_FLAT, NULL,
                   BTN_ID_OFFSET + 1);

        CToolTipCtrl tooltip;
        tooltip.Create(this->m_hWnd, rcDefault, NULL,
                       TTS_BALLOON | TTS_NOPREFIX);

        TOOLINFO ti = {sizeof(ti)};
        ti.hwnd = this->m_hWnd;
        ti.uFlags = TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_SUBCLASS;
        ti.uId = (UINT_PTR)btn.m_hWnd;
        ti.lpszText = (LPWSTR)L"THIS IS A TOOLTIP";
        if (!tooltip.AddTool(&ti)) {
            ocdbg("Could not add tooltip to button.\n");
        }
        tooltip.Activate(TRUE);

        return TRUE;
    }
};
```

For how I run this dialog:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CMyDialog.h"

CAppModule _Module;

int WINAPI wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    _In_ PWSTR pCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
{
    AtlInitCommonControls(ICC_COOL_CLASSES | ICC_BAR_CLASSES);
    HRESULT h_res = _Module.Init(NULL, hInstance);

    {
        CMyDialog dialog;
        dialog.DoModal();
    }

    _Module.Term();
    return 0;
}
```

The call to `tooltip.AddTool(&ti)` returns 0 which notes a failure. I'm assuming this is because the button is not in my resource.h file. Any ideas?

Comment: `CToolTipCtrl tooltip` should not be temporary. It should be declared as member data.

Comment: Also, `ti.hwnd` should probably be assigned `btn.m_hWnd` rather than `this->m_hWnd`.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I don't believe it matters for this case. Nothing changes when I make it a data member.

Comment: @IInspectable The ti.hwnd member is the "Handle to the window that contains the tool." from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-tttoolinfoa. I have tried what you said but to no avail.

Comment: That's poor wording in the documentation, really. It is a handle to the window that handles text lookup, when requested. Since you aren't using the `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK` value, the `ti.hwnd` value is largely meaningless.

Comment: @IInspectable Yeah, the documentation adventure for ATL/WTL has been a ride...

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this by following this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview and adding this to the top of my dialog's header.

```cpp
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Everything is working fine now!

Comment: This should not be necessary since the `TTS_BALLOON` style has been supported since `comctl32.dll` v5.80. If you change `ti.cbSize` to `TTTOOLINFO_V1_SIZE` rather than `sizeof(ti)`, you won't need the `comctl32.dll` v6.0 dependency. You don't need to use the full struct size unless you are using features introduced in newer OS versions (which you are not). Of course, if you need Visual Styles for other aspects of your UI, then by all means, do enable the v6.0 dependency.

Comment: I'll go back and try what you said. I'm actually not using ```TTS_BALLOON``` anymore, but it also wasn't showing with my current ```TTS_POPUP | TTS_NOPREFIX``` style either.

Comment: @RemyLebeau After disabling the v6.0 dependency and setting ```ti.cbSize``` to ```TTTOOLINFO_V1_SIZE```, the tool-tips are working correctly. Thanks! However, I do like the style of the v6.0's buttons and tool-tips. Would editing them to be a similar style be a lot of work?

Comment: yes. So if you like/want the 6.0 feel, then of course use it. I was just pointing out that 6.0 was not strictly needed to get tooltips working.